# Python - writing to file to a given offset

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, binaryfiles

I have a binary file name binary_dump that looks like this

```
xxd binary_dump
0000000: 0000 4865 6c6c 6f20 776f 726c 6421 0000    ..Hello world!..
0000010: 726c 6421 726c 6421                        rld!rld!
```

my objective is with a given offset to write lets say `/00/00/00/00` instead of the string is currently in the given offset

i am using python and this is my code

```
    file = open('binary_dump', "w")
    file.seek(2) 
    data= "\00\00\00\00"
    file.write(data) 
    file.close()
```

what i am getting is this:

```
xxd binary_dump
0000000: 0000 0000 0000                           ......
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are truncating the file with `w` mode and not opening it in binary mode (if you are using Windows). Change the mode from `w` to `r+b`:

```
file = open('binary_dump', "r+b")
```

See Python documentation on [Input and Output](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) for details:

> 'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be erased) [...]. 'r+' opens the file for both reading and writing.

Comment: Even on non-windows environment, adding "b" is a good idea - it will make porting to python 3 easier.

Comment: @C14L Isn't that the whole point? They only want to read from an existing binary file.

Answer (score 1):

Read about the open modes in the docs. The mode you want is most likely `"r+b"`, rather than `"w"` - it won't truncate the file.